# Integrate 2 systems using mirth connecth and hl7

Tags: integration, hl7, mirth-connect

I have 2 systems, the first one has an HL7 Interface, the second has not any interface to communicate with other systems.

I'm about utilizing Mirth Connect on the second system side to receive HL7 messages from the first system and write them direct into the database. Is this a viable option? Or do I need to develop HL7 interface on the second system as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good option.  A lot of systems use integration engines like Mirth, connected to their database layer, to send/receive HL7 mess sages.

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying to do is correct. You must configure a channel in Mirth Connect that the source receives the HL7 (I assume it would be a TCP Listener source), then in the destination you create a database writter connector and record the information you need to integrate.

(Excuse my English)

Comment: I hope it helps you!